# How to get rid from language server background job its irritating too much as well slower eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I am starting the eclipse language server background job is starting. If I click somewhere eclipse is lagging too much.

[image]

Comment: Are you on the latest release?

Comment: Yes its 2022-12

Comment: How can we resolve it @mabi

Comment: @BharatBurle wait for the issue to be resolved, meanwhile disable the Spring Boot Language Server from eclipse Preferences -> Language Servers

Comment: @BharatBurle 4.17.1 has been released, this should fix the issue.

Comment: @BharatBurle please let us know if this solves your problem and accept my answer. thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. In my case it was related to this Spring Tools Suite 4.17.0 issue 925: [OpenRewrite unchecked, but always Language Server Background Job(Loading Rewrite Recipes)](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/925) causing the language server to load the OpenRewrite recipes multiple times.

This issue was fixed in STS release 4.17.1 and updating using `Help` -> `Check for Updates` in Eclipse resolved the problem for me.

Comment: I am using 4.19.0 STS and issue still persists.

Comment: maybe related to https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/1103 ?

Answer (score 2):

> Version: 4.17.0.RELEASE : I also had the same problem of multiple
> Language Server Background Job (Loading rewrite recipes).

**Step 1:** When we click `Window` Menu > `Preferences`  > `Langauge Server` > `Spring Langauge Server` > `Spring Boot Langauge Server` >  **Checkbox : True**  *Start Language Server at startuo when Spring Boot is a dependency preference setting.*
[Spring Boot Langauge Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyY1p.png)

**Step 2:** When we click `Window` Menu > `Preferences`  > `Langauge Server` > `Spring Langauge Server` > `Spring Boot Langauge Server` >  `Open Rewrite` >
**Checkbox : False** *Uncheck all Items*
[Open Rewrite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpe8X.png)

**Step 3:** Click on `Apply and Close` button

**Step 4:** Restart your IDE

I hope this answer will help. Thanks

Comment: I think upgrading STS is a better solution.

Comment: Disabling the Spring Boot Language Server was already suggested in the comments, but just to wait for the fixed version as it also disables STS features.

Comment: This is a valid solution if you work in an environment where you don't have permission to upgrade software versions.

Comment: In Aug 23 even deactivating and restarting was not helping. I uninstalled Spring-Support completely and was surprised how fast the IDE is. Spring Starter you can also use online. The startup-settings you can also use a bit more complicated with standard IDE.